# Joins on search criteria

Tags: magento2, search-criteria, repositories

Is thery any way to join other tables to `SearchCriteriaInterface`, while building it, before calling any `getList` method of any repository? I mean it should work more or less like joining tables on collections. I haven't found anything like this so far.

Joining fields on search result when its implemented by collection is not a way to go, of course.

Comment: I'm faced with same problem. Couldn't find a solution either.